# Asking for a sorting algorithm where data location has a strong correlation with time

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm an intern at a company, and I study math, so my terminologies might be very off.

I have a large database in MongoDB. I would describe some collections like this,

- There is a door where everything goes into, denote this by A**.** All items are recorded in **A**, and some important information is only available in **A**. Every item is given a unique itemID (that is NOT the '_id' automatically given when we insert a document).
- After going through **A**, all items are then sorted to some other collections **B**,**C**,**D**, and each document that went through **A** goes to exactly one of the three. The documents in each collection have their itemID, so theoretically we can match the documents from **B,C,D** with their unique document in **A**.
- All items finally go through **E**, again retaining their itemID.
- There is a somewhat strong correlation between documents in **A** and in **B,C,D** and **E**. Documents in **A,E** contain *time,date*, while documents in **B,C,D** contains *date*. Necessarily for an item, the time is 'smallest' in **A**, then **B/C/D**, then **E**.

What kind of problem am I looking at here? Is there a specific sort/problem that fits my description? Also is it wise to do this in the aggregation pipeline of MongoDB? My pipeline (an intern's) was terribly slow, while a code given to me (to study) uses dictionaries instead, and is much much faster.

Comment: Do you mean "sort" or "partition"?